# How to tell if Excel is still open or if it was closed through Task Manager

Tags: vb.net

So I am opening Excel like so.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

xlApp = DirectCast(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
```

Once it is open, how can I test if the user closed that instance through Task Manager? I tried this.

```
If IsNothing(xlApp) Then...
```

But that returned False when it was open *and* when it was closed through Task Manager.

I will be opening and closing workbooks while the program is open (it will not be visible to the user). Should I just use `Try` when I want to open a new workbook or is there a good way to test if Excel was closed and unavailable so I can reopen it if needed?

Comment: Why are you using `CreateObject()`? You have declared `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application`, so create a new instance of it:  `xlApp = new Excel.Application()`. Your `xlApp` exposes events, among which `WorkbookBeforeClose`. Subscribe to this event, so you get a notification when the WorkBook is closed or the Excel Application closes (unless it's terminated in TaskManager, of course).

Comment: Not sure why I always use ```CreateObject()```. Just a habit at this point. As far as it closing, it will not be visible to the user so the only way it could be closed would be through the Task Manager. I was hoping to test if that happened before I try and open a workbook.

Comment: There's nothing that tells whether the COM object in memory is still *alive*. You *could* save the `xlApp.Hwnd` and compare it with what `DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application", Excel.Application).Hwnd` returns, but that doesn't mean the User has another active Excel app running. So you should call `GetRunningObjectTable()`, which returns an `IRunningObjectTable`, call its `EnumRunning()` method, instantiate an `IMoniker`, use `CreateBindCtx()` to generate an `IBindCtx` to call `[Moniker].GetDisplayName()` to finally get the instances with `[ROT].GetObject([Moniker], [obj])`...

Comment: ... so you can compare the handles. Totally no worthy, IMO, since there's always a race condition lurking. -- You could instantiate the Excel object, do what you need to do, then terminate the Excel instance, create another when needed - hoping nobody has the time to open up TaskManager and terminate the Excel process in the meanwhile - or just catch the (very descriptive) exception when you try to use a COM object that is no longer valid. -- Or, ditch Interop and use one of the different Libraries that allow to work with Excel files without Office.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I am pretty much a self taught hack. :) I just need to open an Excel file and search for part numbers to get pricing. What other libraries are there that I could use for that task? or is there a much better way (probably)?

These Excel files have about 3000 parts in each and each customer has separate pricing so I don't want to have to export the data in any way as the pricing changes from time to time. I just want to be able to open the file, search for x number of items and get the pricing from another column on the match. Any better ideas?

Comment: If that's the Task, you could replace Interop with [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) (last updated yesterday). It's quite simple to use, the base syntax is similar to what you're used to in Office Interop (it's an OpenXML wrapper). It doesn't required an installation of Office (or Excel) -- Install via NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am looking into using ClosedXML instead. Looks like it might be much better suited for this application.